# how to change mongodb string to geoJSON point throughout the collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongodb collection parking_info and this is one document in the collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("559c152fa439a961c357f931"),
"POST_ID" : "354-20160",
"MS_ID" : "-",
"MS_SPACEID" : 0,
"CAP_COLOR" : "Grey",
"METER_TYPE" : "SS",
"SMART_METE" : "Y",
"ACTIVESENS" : "N",
"JURISDICTI" : "SFMTA",
"ON_OFF_STR" : "ON",
"OSP_ID" : 0,
"STREET_NUM" : 2016,
"STREETNAME" : "CHESTNUT ST",
"STREET_SEG" : 3.977e+006,
"RATEAREA" : "Area 5",
"SFPARKAREA" : "Marina",
"LOCATION" : "(37.8007983983, -122.4368696024)"
```

}

I need to convert the last field `"LOCATION" : "(37.8007983983, -122.4368696024)"` 
here the order is latitude , then longitude.
to

`"LOCATION" : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -122.4368696024, 37.8007983983]},`
The coordinate order is longitude, then latitude.

How can I apply that to all documents in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cursor method **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** returned from the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method  to iterate the cursor, access the documents, and with each document modify the LOCATION field by using native JavaScript methods as in the following example:

```
db.parking_info.find({"LOCATION": {"$type": 2}}).forEach(function(doc){
    var obj = {},
        loc = [],
        temp = doc.LOCATION.replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    loc = temp.split(",").map(function(point){
        return parseFloat(point);
    }); 
    obj["type"] = "Point";
    obj["coordinates"] = loc;
    doc.LOCATION = obj;
    db.parking_info.save(doc);    
});
```